# Getting the rightmost element in an unordered_set (or print the contents in reverse)

Tags: c++, set, unordered-set

I have an unordered_set as follow:

```
unordered_set <long> valueSet;

/*the following insertion is done in order (from 1 to 10000), 
 *unordered_set will keep the elements based on the insertion order, right, 
 *just like in a vector ?
**/

for(long i = 1; i <= 10000;++i)
{
        valueSet->insert(i);
}
```

Then I performed another function which erased about 85% of the elements in that unordered_set. (The elements which are to be erased depend on the logic of this function, but it doesn't matter since all the elements were initially inserted in order).

Now after erasing some of the elements in the unordered_set, I want to print the last element which still remains in that unordered_set. For instance, element 9997, 9998, 9999, and 10000 have been erased, so the largest remaining element in this set is 9996. 
How to do this?
If using a basic set, I can do the following:

```
set <long>::reverse_iterator it = valueSet.rbegin();
cout << *it << endl;
```

In a set, we have the reverse_iterator and also rbegin(), but this does not exist in unordered_set. The reason why I did not the basic set is that I need the element size to scale up to 10^8. Using the regular set (which is based on red black trees) will kill the performance indeed (especially when it deals to insertion and deletion). 
How can I do this? Copying the final remaining unordered_set to a vector will work, but of course this will take time. How can I achieve this by using a smarter way? I notice that I also cannot do something like :

```
unordered_set <long>::iterator it = valueSet.end();
//operator -- does not exist here in the unordered_set
it--;
```

Comment: You're trying to have your cake and eat it to.  You gave up the certain benefits when you switched from set to unordered_set, you can't get those benefits back.

Comment: Any other alternative data structure which will allow me to do this? I just wanna get the last element, not to print all the elements in order (as in set). Other data structure implementation from Boost or Google for instance?

Comment: By last element, do you mean "most recently added"? This is easy, just wrap an existing data structure but cache the most recently added element. If you mean anything else, you need a tree.

Comment: I just noticed this comment in your code: *"unordered_set will keep the elements based on the insertion order, right, just like in a vector ?"* No, it will not.

Comment: @VoidStar: Nope, it is very likely  that the most recently added element has already been erased by the second operation. For instance, if I have 10000 elements, and the element 10000, 9999, 9998, 9997 have been erased, so it should print the right most element of the remaining elements in that set (which is 9996). Using a tree would not allow me to insert and remove in O(1), as like in set (which is based on red black tree).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Well if it does not keep the elements based on the insertion order, then yes you are right, so it makes sense for not having the rbegin() operation. But when I copied the remaining elements (which I assumed is in order) using std::copy to a vector, and then print the vector contents (without calling sort), the elements are printed in order. So this prove that the elements in my unordered_set preserve the insertion order. Otherwise, how come I get the elements ordered after calling std::copy and copy it to a vector?

Comment: Deleting from an ordered collection and recovering the space fundamentally costs at least (lg n) time (when the order is not explicitly stored as a number). Trees achieve this speed. But if you don't care about recovering the space, just use a vector and set elements to 0 (or some reserved "empty" thing) and your problem is solved, but you don't get any space back.

Comment: @all_by_grace: It proves that it preserved the order in that particular case, it does not prove that it does this as a general rule. For example: http://ideone.com/LNwDn

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : Yes, right ! In general case it doesn't store the elements in the order of insertion. But it does that only when all the values are also inserted in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ......, 10000). +1 for providing a comparison example to vector.

Comment: @all_by_grace: *"But it does that only when all the values are also inserted in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ......, 10000)"* -- You can't count on that, the specification says no such thing.  It does seem to be the case with GCC(at least in the limited tests I've done), but not with MSVC10.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the clarification ! Yeah, I shouldn't just count on that unusual case. Gracias !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered from your comments, using a [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) or its dynamic counterpart [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) should be appropiate here. You get O(1) insertion and deletion and O(N) for determining the maximum element (by linear search). One could even argue that finding the maximum is amortized O(1), as you have to do at most as many search steps as deletion operations.

Comment: I like the idea of using bitset, and it improves the performance greatly. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

The unordered set is intended to be unordered. You are supposed to assume that the order that you see it's elements in using it's iterator is arbitrary/nondeterministic. This means any specific behavior regarding order is by definition unportable and wholly implementation specific. It may happen to be in order now, but after enough manipulations it could be in another order. The only reason they give you an iterator at all is to allow you to deal with it element by element in some arbitrary order.

Why not just use std::vector from the start?

Comment: Yes, true. The thing is I that I don't do any manipulations which will alter the order of the elements. Because I just need to insert in the beginning (let's say : ordered elements from 1 to 1000000), and then I will only do a remove operation and no further insertion. std::vector is slow for removal of elements (especially removal in the middle or in the beginning). Unordered_set allows me to insert and remove in O(1) since it is implemented using hash table.

Comment: When you say "at the beginning" you are still thinking "ordered". It sounds like you want some kind of tree then, maybe a B+ tree.

Comment: I said "at the beginning", meaning that I only inserted all the elements once (and I will not violate this rule), and will not insert any other values to this set, but I will only removing some of the existing values (which will not alter the order because no more insertion are being done). I am looking for a smarter way, like getting a reference to that memory location of the last value by using a pointer, and print that element. Phew....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have your cake and eat it.

Unordered containers store their elements in an unordered fashion (typically inside a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)), so you cannot iterate over them in a predictable way. In particular, **they don't store the elements in the order they are inserted**.

If you don't care about the order, then you're better with `std::deque` or `std::vector` (prefer the former if you have to insert at the front).

Comment: Yes, right ! In general case it doesn't store the elements in the order of insertion. But it does, when all the values are also inserted in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ......, 10000). Deque or vector does not allow deletion in O(1) :-) I was just inspired by the Java LinkedHashSet, which distinguish it from the regular HashSet, since it preserves the ordering. Anyway, thanks !!

Comment: But vector and deque let you *clear* an item in constant time which would get you to the same end.

Answer (score 0):

Store the deleted items in a vector. When done, convert to a heap. (O(n), where n is the number of deleted items) Then repeatedly remove the maximum value from the heap until you find the highest element not deleted. That's O(m log n), where m is the difference between your maximum value and the answer.